# Flip Window Animation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Over the last few days, I've been trying to flip the window when loading. I was able to do several window effects, however I need to flip the window when loading.

For example, in the new version of Skype, when you are on a call, if you want to add another person to the conversation you can click on the "add people" button and the contact list will load into the current conversation window with a small flipping effect. I need to incorporate the same effect in my application.

To get a basic idea about form animations, I read the following code samples.

[1 Fade Effect](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/FadePage.aspx)

[2 Slide Animation and Fade Effect](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FormAnimation.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add moving effects to my controls in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102241/how-can-i-add-moving-effects-to-my-controls-in-c)

Comment: im sorry to say, noop its not my if you ever visited to my referenced links you will never add this comment to this and that thread is much more similar  to this 
   Differences are 
           This Thread im talking about window transition 
           and flip effect but in your link it describes about fade and slide transition for windows form's controls

Comment: Your English is very hard to decipher.  Nevertheless, the linked articles also use AnimateWindow.  It is not just for controls.

Comment: im sorry hans English is not my 1st language please forgive me. you are correct hans but my problem is flipping a window like in skype AnimateWindow API function does not support for flipping it can do fading and slide transitions. if you can manage to find some sample cording to flip a control or a window, please do post it as a answer, appreciate if you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely looking for the [**dot-net-transitions**](http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/) project, which is an open source project that contains animation support for Windows Forms projects.  For example, you can adjust the size or location of controls using different algorithms, including:

- Linear
- Acceleration
- Critical Damping
- Ease In / Out
- Bounce
- Throw and Catch
- Flash

For more info see:

http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/wiki/CodingWithTransitions

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps what you want is to animate a 3-D transformation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753347.aspx

Comment: -1 The question clearly asks for a WinForms solution, not WPF.