# Make controls disappear sidely

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add moving effects to my controls in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102241/how-can-i-add-moving-effects-to-my-controls-in-c)

I'm work on on a C# WinForms  project, and I created a login form.

I want when I click in a link in this login form to make the controls in the login form to disappear sidely (like the effect in iPad when you move your finger on it) and other controls to be appeared .

Is there any chance to make this possible (using WinForm)?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/

Answer (score 0):

Check DevExpress slider controls for Windows Forms.

You should find some examples here :

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/index.xml

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/toolbar_menu.xml (slide menu effecT)