# Simple Movement in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, location

I want a label to move from the left of the form and stop at the center

I have been able to do this using

```
    Timer tmr = new Timer();
    int locx = 6;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tmr.Interval = 2;
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Location = new Point(locx, 33);
        locx++;
        if (locx == 215)
        {
            tmr.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "QUICK SPARK";
        tmr.Start();
    }
```

I want to know if there is any better way to do this???...Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hans Passant has an excellent answer on the built in functionality of windows for this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6103677/1324033)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using VS 2012 and C# 5, you can do this simply via `await`/`async`:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "QUICK SPARK";

    for (int locx = 6; locx < 215; ++locx)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2);
        label1.Location = new Point(locx, 33);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm actually using Visual-Studio-2005 & 2008

Comment: @Precious1tj Then your option is likely the best.

Comment: I think Reed nailed it, with one more suggestion - is your form a static size, or is it user-resizeable? You might want to calculate the midpoint rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: @RobH I agree, and think basing off the form's size is probably appropriate.  However, this is going to be quite fast (less than a half second) and is happening on form load, so it's unlikely that the user will be able to resize in time for it to be a problem in practice.

Comment: True, though the other (probably more important) reason I neglected to mention was maintainability - so when the next developer comes along and is told to resize the form, he doesn't need to know that there are implicit dependencies like this.

Answer (score 0):

> **WinForm Animation Library [.Net3.5+]**
>
> A simple library for animating controls/values in .Net WinForm (.Net
>   3.5 and later). Key frame (Path) based and fully customizable.

https://falahati.github.io/WinFormAnimation/

```
new Animator2D(
        new Path2D(new Float2D(-100, -100), c_control.Location.ToFloat2D(), 500))
    .Play(c_control, Animator2D.KnownProperties.Location);
```

This moves the `c_control` control from -100, -100 to the location it was in first place in 500 ms.