# Usercontrol with transparent backcolor when animating, it is not visible

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a usercontrol which has transparent background. I use this usercontrol on windows form and do some animation stuff on control when a button is clicked.
myctrl is usercontrol created in windows form. Below is code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Point p1 = new Point(myctrl.Location.X, myctrl.Location.Y);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                myctrl.Location = new Point(p1.X + i, p1.Y + i);

                myctrl.Update();
                pictureBox1.Update();
                i++;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
}
```

Problem : Once loop starts usercontrol is not visible and when loop ends control is visible.
Also, I'm placing the control on picturebox which is placed on winforms.

Comment: Hanging the UI thread for 10 seconds never works well, Windows gets pretty cranky about it, for one.  Use a Timer instead.

Comment: @Hans-- it worked.. using timer.. thanx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have to use `Refresh` instead of `Update`.

Or you may completely change how you do it once you read about [`AnimateWindow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102241/how-can-i-add-moving-effects-to-my-controls-in-c/6103677#6103677).

### Edit

I must be blind to not notice a clear ussue with your *animation*. The point is, you doing it at once (with naive `Thread.Sleep`). And while you doing it, repainting is blocked (even if you call `Refresh` you will not see result). So yes, for a duration of animation there will be nothing visible.

What you have to do is to split animation (by using `Timer` more likely) into frames and display only one frame at once.